Backend Peticiones Fantasma o Encoladas Whatsapp API
Estoy útilizando Whatsapp API sin intermediarios para poder trabajar un chatbot pero no comprendo por que a veces quedan ciertas peticiones "fantasmas" y les envia mensajes a los números de telefono pese a que ellos ya no hayan interactuado y eso a veces suele ocurrir otras veces no sucede desconozco el motivo asi que apreciaria mucho el apoyo ¿Como podria corregirlo? comparto mi código encargado de manejar las peticiones del webhook:
whatsappRouter.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.object && req.body.entry && req.body.entry[0].changes && req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages) {
        for (const message of req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages) {
            const phone_number_id = req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.metadata.phone_number_id;
            const from = message.from;
            const msg_body = message.text ? message.text.body.toLowerCase() : null;
            const image_data = message.image ? message.image : null;
            const audioUrl = message.audio ? message.audio.id : null;
            const location = message.location ? message.location : null;
            const longitude = location ? location.longitude : null;
            const latitude = location ? location.latitude : null;


            const command = {
                phoneNumberId: phone_number_id,
                from: from,
                messageBody: msg_body,
                imageUrl: image_data ? image_data.id : null,
                audioUrl: audioUrl,
                latitude: latitude,
                longitude: longitude
            };
            console.log(command);

            await whatsappCommandHandler.handleCommand(command);
        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
});

whatsappRouter.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    const VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.WebhookKey;

    const mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
    const token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
    const challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];

    if (mode && token) {
        if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
            console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
            res.status(200).send(challenge);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    }
});

export default whatsappWebhook;

